# A component required a bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I just tried springboot through the tutorial but when I run it shows an error. i dont understand about this error.

"Description:

Parameter 0 of method setEmf in com.mii.tugas.Dao.MahasiswaDao required a bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' in your configuration."

this my com.mii.tugas.Dao.MahasiswaDao :

```
import com.mii.tugas.model.Mahasiswa;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.mii.tugas.interfaces.MahasiswaServices;

@Service
public class MahasiswaDao implements MahasiswaServices {

    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @Autowired
    public void setEmf(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        this.emf = emf;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Mahasiswa> listMahasiswa() {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        return em.createQuery("from Data_Mahasiswa", Mahasiswa.class).getResultList();
    }
}
```

and this my MahasiswaServices :

```
import com.mii.tugas.model.Mahasiswa;
import java.util.List;

public interface MahasiswaServices {
    List <Mahasiswa> listMahasiswa();
}
```

My Pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mii</groupId>
    <artifactId>tugas</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>tugas</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: try this  @PersistenceUnit
              EntityManagerFactory emf;

Comment: Not sure but you also need to set `application.properties` for JPA: reference: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing EclipseLink and JPA. Clean up the pom.xml first:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mii</groupId>
    <artifactId>tugas</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>tugas</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
           <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Then you don't need to inject the `EntityMangerFactory` you can directly inject the `EntityManager`

But you even don't the `EntityManger`!

Please read the documentation of Spring Data JPA: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#reference